# Merge two data.tables based on AND condition and add third column

Tags: if-statement, merge, conditional-statements, data.table

I have two data.tables "commuters_old" and "commuter_new":

commuters_old: (1.703.000 observations)

| from1 | to1 | amount1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 1001 | 12 |
| 1001 | 1002 | 2 |
| 1001 | 1003 | 23 |
| 2000 | 1002 | 200 |
| 2001 | 2001 | 80 |
| 2001 | 2002 | 98 |

commuters_new: (1.400.000 observations)

| from2 | to2 | amount2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 1001 | 10 |
| 1001 | 1002 | 22 |
| 1001 | 1004 | 2 |
| 2000 | 1002 | 50 |
| 2001 | 2001 | 8 |
| 2001 | 2003 | 100 |

```
library(data.table)

commuters_old <- data.table(
  from1 = c(1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 2000L, 2001L, 2001L),
  to1 = c(1001L, 1002L, 1003L, 1002L, 2001L, 2002L),
  amount1 = c(12L, 2L, 23L, 200L, 80L, 98L))

commuters_new <- data.table(
  from2 = c(1000L, 1001L, 1001L, 2000L, 2001L, 2001L),
  to2 = c(1001L, 1002L, 1004L, 1002L, 2001L, 2003L),
  amount2 = c(10L, 22L, 2L, 50L, 8L, 100L))
```

I would like to add the column "amount1" to data.table "commuters_new" but only if "from1 == from2" AND "to1 == to2". If this condition is not met, I want to write 0, so that:

commuters_new:

| from2 | to2 | amount2 | amount1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 1001 | 10 | 0 |
| 1001 | 1002 | 22 | 2 |
| 1001 | 1004 | 2 | 0 |
| 2000 | 1002 | 50 | 200 |
| 2001 | 2001 | 8 | 80 |
| 2001 | 2003 | 100 | 0 |

After that merge, I want to add another column "factor" that gives me the factor of "amount2" and"amount1".

commuters_new:

| from2 | to2 | amount2 | amount1 | factor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 1001 | 10 | 0 | 0 |
| 1001 | 1002 | 22 | 2 | 11 |
| 1001 | 1004 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 2000 | 1002 | 50 | 200 | 0.25 |
| 2001 | 2001 | 8 | 80 | 0.1 |
| 2001 | 2003 | 100 | 0 | 0 |

What I have tried:

```
commuters_new[, amount1 := ifelse(from1==from2 & to1==to2, commuters_old$amount1, 0)]
```

OR

```
commuters_new$amount1[, paste(ifelse(from1==from2 & to1==to2, commuters_old$amount1, 0))]
```

But I always get the error:

> Supplied 1703144 items to be assigned to 1408969 items of column 'amount1'. If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep() to make this intent clear to readers of your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way, using [dtplyr](https://dtplyr.tidyverse.org/):

Steps:

1. Load it as a lazy data table
2. Perform a left join, joining new on old
3. Replace the empty values in our new `amount1` column with `0`s
4. If `amount1` is 0, `factor` is `0`. Otherwise, it is `amount2 / amount1`
5. Tell `dtplyr` to run the code by running `as.data.table()`

```
pacman::p_load(data.table, dtplyr, tidyverse)

commuters_new |>
  lazy_dt() |>
  left_join(commuters_old, by = c("from2" = "from1", "to2" = "to1")) |>
  replace_na(list(amount1 = 0L))|>
  mutate(factor = ifelse(!amount1, 0, amount2 / amount1)) |>
  as.data.table()
```

Equivalent data.table code:

```
setnames(setcolorder(`_DT34`[`_DT33`, on = .(from1 = from2, to1 = to2), 
    allow.cartesian = TRUE], c(1L, 2L, 4L, 3L)), c("from1", "to1"
), c("from2", "to2"))[, `:=`(amount1 = fcoalesce(amount1, 0L))][, 
    `:=`(factor = fifelse(amount1 == 0, 0, amount2/amount1))]
# or
out <- (commuters_old[commuters_new, on = .(from1 = from2, to1 = to2)]
       [, amount1 := fcoalesce(amount1, 0L)]
       [, factor := ifelse(!amount1, 0, amount2 / amount1)])
```

Output:

```
   from1  to1 amount1 amount2 factor
1:  1000 1001       0      10   0.00
2:  1001 1002       2      22  11.00
3:  1001 1004       0       2   0.00
4:  2000 1002     200      50   0.25
5:  2001 2001      80       8   0.10
6:  2001 2003       0     100   0.00
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `right_join` and `mutate` functions from the dplyr package:

```
library(dplyr)

commuters <- right_join(commuters_old, commuters_new, by = c("from1" = "from2",
                                                            "to1" = "to2"))
# change NAs to 0s
commuters[is.na(commuters)] <- 0 # check if there are no NAs in your from and to

#calculate factor
mutate(rowwise(commuters), factor = amount2/amount1)
```

Comment: I think it is a left_join backboned? `I would like to add the column "amount1" to data.table "commuters_new" but only if "from1 == from2" AND "to1 == to2".`

Comment: You're right, thank you. Except if you have old before new it's a right join.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `data.table`'s [`merge`](https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/reference/merge.html) to add the data from the second data to the first dataset.

Eg something like this

```
merge(commuters_old, commuters_new,
      by.x = c("from1", "to1"), by.y = c("from2", "to2"),
      all.x = TRUE)
```

Also, the error you are seeing regarding recycling indicates that you have duplicate values. This is especially nasty when the second (commuters_new) dataset has duplicate entries as this will duplicate corresponding values in the first dataset.

Comment: this is great, but it doesn't create the factor column, nor does it replace the NAs with 0s